# Deseriallization of complex XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have an compex XML like the following:

```
<rootentity name='xyz'>
<cascadingentities>
    <cascadingentity name='xyz'>
        <fetchXML>
            <fetch>
                <entity name='xyz' >
                    <attribute name='xyz' />
                    <filter type='and' >
                      <condition attribute='xyz' operator='eq' value='{xyz}' />
                    </filter>
                </entity>
            </fetch>
        </fetchXML>
        <cascadingentities>
            <cascadingentity name='xyz'>
                <fetchXML>
                    <fetch>
                        <entity name='xyz' >
                            <attribute name='xyz' />
                            <filter type='and' >
                              <condition attribute='xyz' operator='eq' value='{xyz}' />
                            </filter>
                        </entity>
                    </fetch>
                </fetchXML>
                <cascadingentities>
                    <cascadingentity name='xyz'>
                        <fetchXML>
                            <fetch>
                                <entity name='xyz' >
                                    <attribute name='xyz' />
                                    <filter type='and' >
                                      <condition attribute='xyz' operator='eq' value='{xyz}' />
                                    </filter>
                                </entity>
                            </fetch>
                        </fetchXML>                         
                    </cascadingentity>
                </cascadingentities>
            </cascadingentity>                                              
        </cascadingentities>
    </cascadingentity>
    <cascadingentity name='xyz'>
        <fetchXML>
            <fetch>
                <entity name='xyz' >
                    <attribute name='xyz' />
                    <filter type='and' >
                      <condition attribute='xyz' operator='eq' value='{xyz}' />
                    </filter>
                </entity>
            </fetch>
        </fetchXML>                         
    </cascadingentity>
</cascadingentities>
```

I need to deserialize the whole thing into c# classes. Note that this has to be done recursively because certain elements are nested.

my class definition looks as follows:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "rootentity")]
public class Rootentity
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "cascadingentities")]
    public Cascadingentities Cascadingentities { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "cascadingentities")]
public class Cascadingentities
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "cascadingentity")]
    public Cascadingentity Cascadingentity { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "cascadingentity")]
public class Cascadingentity
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "fetchXML")]
    public FetchXML FetchXML { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "fetchXML")]
public class FetchXML
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "fetch")]
    public Fetch Fetch { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "fetch")]
public class Fetch
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "entity")]
    public Entity Entity { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "entity")]
public class Entity
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "attribute")]
    public Attribute Attribute { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "filter")]
    public Filter Filter { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "attribute")]
public class Attribute
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "filter")]
public class Filter
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "condition")]
    public Condition Condition { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "condition")]
public class Condition
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "attribute")]
    public string Attribute { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "operator")]
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Nesting]

Note that the element "cascadingentities" can be nested within "cascadingentity"

Could please anybody point me to the right direction on how this can be achieved? maybe with some code sample?

any help is greatly appreciated.

kind regards

Comment: You can auto-generate the classes using xsd.exe; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-def-tool-gen

Comment: `cascadingentities` should be a `List<cascadingentity>` property.
That way you can serialize that collection.
What exactly is not working here?
Besides the missing List, it looks alright.

Comment: thx for the replies.

where I'm struggling a bit is how to implement this, specially the recursion part.

Comment: Thx HankTheHank for your hint. How exactly should this be?

Comment: When I use xsd.exe I get the error:

The same table 'cascadingentities' cannot be the child table in two nested relations.”

Comment: try

`
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "rootentity")]
public class Rootentity
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "cascadingentities")]
    public List<CascadingEntity> Cascadingentities { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
`

for the "collection"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for me, i needed to add the closing tag in the xml though "":

---

```
    void Main()
{
    var rootelement = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Rootentity)).Deserialize(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlText)));

}

// Define other methods and classes here

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "rootentity")]
public class Rootentity
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "cascadingentities")]
    public Cascadingentities Cascadingentities { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "cascadingentities")]
public class Cascadingentities
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "cascadingentity")]
    public Cascadingentity Cascadingentity { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "cascadingentity")]
public class Cascadingentity
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "fetchXML")]
    public FetchXML FetchXML { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "fetchXML")]
public class FetchXML
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "fetch")]
    public Fetch Fetch { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "fetch")]
public class Fetch
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "entity")]
    public Entity Entity { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "entity")]
public class Entity
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "attribute")]
    public Attribute Attribute { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "filter")]
    public Filter Filter { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "attribute")]
public class Attribute
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "filter")]
public class Filter
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "condition")]
    public Condition Condition { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "condition")]
public class Condition
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "attribute")]
    public string Attribute { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "operator")]
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

string xmlText = @"<rootentity name='xyz'>
<cascadingentities>
    <cascadingentity name='xyz'>
        <fetchXML>
            <fetch>
                <entity name='xyz' >
                    <attribute name='xyz' />
                    <filter type='and' >
                      <condition attribute='xyz' operator='eq' value='{xyz}' />
                    </filter>
                </entity>
            </fetch>
        </fetchXML>
        <cascadingentities>
            <cascadingentity name='xyz'>
                <fetchXML>
                    <fetch>
                        <entity name='xyz' >
                            <attribute name='xyz' />
                            <filter type='and' >
                              <condition attribute='xyz' operator='eq' value='{xyz}' />
                            </filter>
                        </entity>
                    </fetch>
                </fetchXML>
                <cascadingentities>
                    <cascadingentity name='xyz'>
                        <fetchXML>
                            <fetch>
                                <entity name='xyz' >
                                    <attribute name='xyz' />
                                    <filter type='and' >
                                      <condition attribute='xyz' operator='eq' value='{xyz}' />
                                    </filter>
                                </entity>
                            </fetch>
                        </fetchXML>                         
                    </cascadingentity>
                </cascadingentities>
            </cascadingentity>                                              
        </cascadingentities>
    </cascadingentity>
    <cascadingentity name='xyz'>
        <fetchXML>
            <fetch>
                <entity name='xyz' >
                    <attribute name='xyz' />
                    <filter type='and' >
                      <condition attribute='xyz' operator='eq' value='{xyz}' />
                    </filter>
                </entity>
                </fetch>
            </fetchXML>                         
        </cascadingentity>
    </cascadingentities>
</rootentity>";
```

Comment: Hi Tom

Thank you very much for the feedback. But as you can see there is a recursion, so the element "cascadingentities" is nested within sub-elements and there is no restriction. It can be nested multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

try

    `[XmlRoot(ElementName = "rootentity")]
    public class Rootentity
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "cascadingentities")]
        public List<CascadingEntity> Cascadingentities { get; set; } 
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }`

for the "collection" This allows multiple embedded
    `Cascadingentity`
elements.
the XML serializer supports lists.

you won't need the `Cascadingentities` type anymore at all then...